# Return error message if client doesnt exist or is empty

Tags: c#, soap, service

Currently I create a Test Application to test my SOAP services, and everything works fine, and right now I want to return error message if user input ID which doesnt exist in DB or if miss to enter ID in textbox.
[image]

The error messaga should appear in txtRezultat or pop up message, doesnt matter.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AkontoService.AkontasSoapClient client = new AkontoService.AkontasSoapClient();           
            var respons = client.GetAkontasById(txtAkonto.Text);
            txtRezultat.Text = respons;
        }
```

Comment: Removing oracle tag as it has nothing to do with Oracle DB.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see this. Removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the content of the response before setting the content.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AkontoService.AkontasSoapClient client = new AkontoService.AkontasSoapClient();
        var respons = client.GetAkontasById(txtAkonto.Text);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(respons))
        {
            txtRezultat.Text = "Error: Client not found!";
        }
        else
        {
            txtRezultat.Text = respons;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works now 
Insded of  string.IsNullOrEmpty(respons) I put response != null that's why I couldnt get error message.

Comment: @Xerror This is because the response from your SOAP service is not null :)